# How to get table name in MYSQL and fill combobox with that name?

Tags: php, html

I am newbabie in PHP.
I want to get table name from MYSQL, put that name to combobox. When I select combobox I will get the selected name to select query and print the table I chose.

For example:
In mysql I have some table: **book_economy**, **book_techology**, **book_magazine** and some table a,b,c,d...

I only want to get 3 table (**book_economy, book_techology, book_magazine**) into combobox.

And then, when I chose book_economy I will put this name to SQL select query "*Select * from book_economy....*" and print information of this table.

Now I can filter these table, but I have problem to put these value to combobox and get selected value. Please help me, thank you.

Here is my code

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
?> 
    $db= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$db)
    {
        echo "CAN'T CONNECT DATABASE";
        exit;
    }
$table= mysql_query("show tables from data2 LIKE '%book_%'");
echo "<select name = 'venue' >";
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($table)) != null)
{
    echo "<option value = '{$row['0']}'";
    if ($selected_venue_id == $row['0'])
    echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row['0']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: What is your question?You have error or ...?

Comment: Your combobox  is empty?

Comment: No, It filled, but I can't get selected value from it. :(

Comment: What is your code for get selected value?

Comment: I don't know how to get, I have written echo $a = $_POST['venue']; but it not work

Comment: Check my answer to get table names

Comment: try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` it is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

It will be much better to create only one table, and add column "category", where you write category for each record, then when you want to get categories you wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Book;
```

To list only books from category use:

```
SELECT * FROM Book WHERE Category = 'CATEGORY';
```

Or even better to create separate table "Categories" with id and name, then only put category_id in Book table.